# Showing composite objects on the view by the presenter

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, mvp, composition

I have a MVP triad `WageInfo` the Model, `WageView` the View, and `WagePresenter` the Presenter. `WageInfo` has composite object lists called `List<Earning> EarningList`, `List<Deduction> DeductionList` and `List<WageBalance> WageBalanceList`.

My presenter wants to show Earnings, Deductions and WageBalances in three separate `DataGridViews` on the View. So the presenter ask `WageInfo` and then `WageInfo` gets data from `DataService` and create all three lists and it'll return a `WageInfo` instance which contains all object lists to the presenter then the presenter choose what to show on the View as follows.

```
class WagePresenter
{
    var wageInfo = WageInfo.GetEarnings(); // return a WageInfo instance
    _View.Earnings = wageInfo.EarningList; // choose EarningList to show on the view
}


class WageInfo
{
    public List<Earning> EarningList; // composition of EarningList in WageInfo
    // Other lists



    public WageInfo()
    {
        EarningList = new List<Earning>();
        // Instantiate other lists



    }

    public WageInfo GetEarnings()
    {
        this.EarningList = CreateEarningList();
        return this; // return current instance of WageInfo
    }

    private List<Earning> CreateEarningList()
    {
        var dataTable = _DataService.GenerateEarnings(); // DataService returns a DataTable
        return ConvertDataTableToList(dataTable); 

    }

    private List<Earning> ConvertDataTableToList(DataTable dt)
    {
        //Use data in the dt to create a list of Earning objects
        return list;
    }
}
```

I just want to know whether I have broken the composition here by declaring `EarningList` etc. public?

If I declare `EarningList` private then I could have a public method in `WageInfo` which returns a `EarningList`. Is it a better way to do than declaring `EarningList` public?

If both options are not ok then how does my presenter show each list in separate `DataGridViews`?

EDIT : Class Earning looks as follows...

```
class Earning
{
    public EmployeeID {get; set;}
    public BasicSalary {get; set;}
    public OverTime {get; set;}
    public Allowance {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: IMHO, it's fine, but I'd keep the `get public` and `set private`

Comment: Also methods are better choice especially if you have scenarios like condition based evaluation or lazy loading etc., otherwise your approach should be good enough.

Comment: @AD.Net, I'm using public `Set` here as I currently instantiate objects like this without using constructor > `new Earning { EmployeeID = emp_id, BasicSalary = basic_salary,...};` Is it always bad?